# How to update JSlider.getValue()

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I am playing around with common Swing components in java, and is struggling to figure out how to update JSlider.getValue().

Do I need to add a changelistener and an if Loop to check whether or not JSlider.getValueIsAdjusting() and then return the updated value?

How would one do this? Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Slider gui = new Slider();
}

JSlider slide = new JSlider(0, 100);

public Slider(){
    super("Swing Slider");
    setSize(300,200);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    add(pnl);
    setVisible(true);

    slide.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
    slide.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
    slide.setPaintTicks(true);
    slide.setPaintLabels(true);
    slide.setToolTipText("The value is: " + slide.getValue());
    pnl.add(slide);
}
```

For example I was able to get the initial value of the slider(which is 50),

[but when I adjust the slider, the value displayed is still 50, how do i update this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNc7q.png)

Comment: You need it in one of the slider's events. Not the Constructor of your class.

Comment: Where's the code you're using to update the tooltip state?

Comment: There is a tutorial that explains how to use a JSlider: [How to use a JSlider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html). Start here.

Comment: Considering I dont have an updater for my tooltip state, I think thats my problem.

Comment: [Google search for some similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+jslider+get++value)

Comment: Your tool tip String  is currently determined once at creation and then stays the same. If you want it updated, then you will have to update it from within a ChangeListener.

Comment: I got it to work now, its a small bit weird since the toolTipText will only show its label once the slider has been moved.